# Accidentally posted answer instead of comment

Tags: support, comments, not-an-answer

I noticed the day after I posted a comment to a question that I accidentally posted it as an answer. After down-voting an answer, the popup pointed out that it would be useful to tell the reason for the down-vote, and apparently I didn't pay enough attention to where it was going.

I don't mind the down-vote on my answer, and I'm happy it got deleted right away (because yes, mine was definitely not an answer either), but it would be nice to change it as a comment into the answer I down-voted so it'd possibly be useful and the person who submitted the answer would improve on it.

Is there any way my answer could be turned into a comment into the correct place? Is it possible for me to do it manually, is there a mechanism that does it automatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do it manually, it is far easier.

There is a mechanism that can do it automatically, but it is only available to moderators and used when low-rep users post otherwise helpful comments as an answer. You'd have to flag your post for moderator attention and request they convert the post, but since this is *easily* done yourself, please don't go bother the already very busy moderators about this. It's not like it is *hard*.